# Slice a substring from a cyclic bitset

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitset

I have a (cyclic) `bitset<N>` and would like to retrieve the substring `i...i+K-1` (where it could happen that `i = N - 1; K = 5`, so it has to wrap around and get `N-1; 0; 1; 2; 3`), as another `bitset<K>` (K is of course known at compile-time)

The obvious thing doesn't work because `operator &` doesn't allow operands of different sizes (although it would be trivial?)

```
bitset<N> data = ...;
bitset<K> mask; mask = ~mask;
bitset<K> rotated = in << i | in >> (K - i);
bitset<K> slice = rotated & mask;
```

The next best thing doesn't work with large `N`

```
bitset<K> slice( rotated.to_ullong() & mask.to_ullong() );
```

What to do, short of implementing `bitset<min<N,K>::value> operator &(bitset<N>,bitset<K>)`? (and maybe not as terribly inefficient, this approach copies the set 3 times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen none of the bitset public member functions support copying between bitsets of different sizes.  The convert to ulong function isn't useful if you have sets that won't fit in a ulong.  I don't see why the standard couldn't at least have a copy constructor and assignment operator that supported different sizes.  That said given the standard class I don't see any way around copying the bits one at a time.

I'd suggest something like the following:

```
template⟨size_t D_SZ,size_t S_SZ⟩
void CopyBitset(std::bitset⟨D_SZ⟩ &dest, const std::bitset⟨S_SZ⟩ &source,size_t idx,
    size_t count,size_t destidx=0)
{
        for(size_t i = 0; i != count;++i){
                dest.set((i + destidx) % D_SZ, source[(i + idx) % S_SZ]);      
        }
}
```

At least the shift and copy operations are combined. 
You might also take a look at boost's dynamic bitset to see if it would more closely match your usage .